# Form Validation Android

Tags: android, regex, validation

I was wondering what is the best way to validate form ?

I did try the following:

```
EditText fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
String fname_text = fname.getText().toString; 
if(fname_text.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            fname.setError("Field is required");
        }
```

and also:

```
fname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
        {           
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){

            }           
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after){

            }           
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
            {

                Pattern mPattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]{2,20}$");

                Matcher matcher = mPattern.matcher(s.toString());               
                if(!matcher.matches())       // on Success 
                { 
                    fname.setError("Please make sure you input a valid first name");

                }
              }
        });
```

The thing that I am confused in is that ... whenever the page loads for the first time, the error message is shown, but when I go inside the EditText and type some content, and if I erase the content, the error message does not persist. So how do I keep this validation persistent ??? Because the way that the program is shaping up, it looks like it won't validate anything very nicely. And you guys know some good links for regex in android with complete example, please do recommend.

And also, how will me putting the Pattern and Matcher methods in onTextChanged or beforeTextChanged affect the output ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the check right after

```
EditText fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
String fname_text = fname.getText().toString;
```

Use an [OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) and run it whenever the [onFocusChange()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html#onFocusChange%28android.view.View,%20boolean%29) method is called. Ideally, you'd run it only when the View loses focus. Something like:

```
EditText fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
String fname_text = fname.getText().toString; 
fname.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
        if(!(v.isFocused())) {
            //Run your validation
        }
    }
});
```

This way, you only run the Validation when the user is done typing, instead of everytime the user changes something.